# Использование CmsSigner и GostCryptography с сертификатом, приватный ключ которого находится в запароленном контейнере VipNet

Tags: c#, цифровая-подпись

Использую [GostCryptography](https://github.com/AlexMAS/GostCryptography), для создания открепленной (CMS Sign, PKCS7) подписи. Пользуюсь примером из тестового проекта "SignedCmsSignTest", идущего вместе с исходниками. Никак не получается программно указать пароль контейнера VipNet для создания автоматизации ЦП. Для **обычного шифрования/подписи данных проблем не возникает**, но в случае создания открепленной подписи, в классах GostSignedCms и NET CmsSigner нет возможности указать пароль контейнера приватного ключа или Алгоритм подписи с уже заданным ключом.

Даже когда использую конструктор public CmsSigner (CspParameters parameters) и в CspParameters, заполненным параметрами из сертификата добавляю SecureString с необходимым паролем и флагом подавления окна cspKeyParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoPromp - все равно во время выполнения VipNet вываливает диалоговое окно с предложением ввести пароль контейнера.

```
var cspKeyParams = certificate.GetPrivateKeyInfo();
cspKeyParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt;
cspKeyParams.KeyPassword = secStr;
var signer = new CmsSigner(cspKeyParams);
```

Судя по исходникам NET эти два параметра CspParameters просто игнорируются в недрах класса CmsSigner.

Кто-нибудь решал эту задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После пары недель изучения вопроса выяснилось, что задать пароль контейнера в контесте поставленного вопроса невозможно, как и принудительно указать алгоритм с заранее введенным паролем. NET Класс CmsSigner, просто не обладают таким функционалом и нет какого-либо обходного пути, в том числе не подошло решение открыть контейнер заранее, с помощью к.л. криптографической операции.
В итоге за два дня был освоен JAVA и решение было написано на прилагающейся к VipNet CSP SDK JCrypto библиотеке, которая оказалась весма удобной и на которую есть масса документации от разработчиков и затем, с помощью микросервиса, полученный модуль был соединен с основным проектом на NET.

Answer (score 0):

Используя GostCryptography мне удалось программно указать пароль контейнера.
Ниже приведу пример

```
 X509Certificate2 cert=mycert;
 var privateKeyInfo = cert.GetPrivateKeyInfo();
 var privateKey = new Gost_R3410_2012_256_AsymmetricAlgorithm(privateKeyInfo);
 privateKey.SetContainerPassword(CryptoService.CreateSecureString("123456789"));

 SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo);
 CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(privateKeyInfo)
 {
     Certificate = cert
 };
```

Gost_R3410_2012_256_AsymmetricAlgorithm - Зависит от типа алгоритма которую вы используете